# How do I upgrade wine in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: upgrade, wine

I am trying to run windows office 2007 enterprise on Ubuntu 12.04. I have been able to launch and write something on it. But it crashes when I try to save anything. Since Office 2007 has got a good score, I think the problem is in my current version of Wine (1.4). Maybe I shall upgrade it to Wine 1.6, but I don't know how. I have made some research and I didn't find anything helpful. Could you please help me?! Thank you

Comment: http://www.winehq.org/download/ubuntu

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add repository `ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa`

```
 sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa
```

Then install `wine1.6`

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install wine1.6
```

ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa has wine1.6

Answer (score 1):

Or just download

https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-wine/+archive/ppa/+files/wine1.6_1.6.1-0ubuntu1~ppa1~precise1_amd64.deb

and install using software centre